# Numpy ndarray unexpected shape broadcast error

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have one numpy ndarray with shape (3,). I have another ndarray with shape (3,100,100). The following works:

```
a = np.array([1,1,1]) # Shape is (3,)
b = np.zeros((3,100,100)) # Shape is (3,100,100)
c = np.array([b[0], b[1], 0]) # Shape (3,)
c - a # works fine and as expected
```

But the following breaks:

```
c_wrong = np.array([b[0], b[1], b[2]]) # now c_wrong is (3,100,100) too

c_wrong - a # ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,100,100) (3,)
```

Is there a way to reshape a (3,100,100) into a (3,)?

An ugly walk around that I figured out is just to add a dummy extra component:

```
>>> c_wrong = np.array([b[0],b[1],b[2],0])
>>> a = np.array([1,1,1,1])
>>> d = c_wrong - a
>>> d[0:3]
```

This is quite ugly though, but I hope it  helps to understand the problem and the desired behavior.

Comment: The variable `r_1` is not defined in your code!

Comment: @JoeIddon sorry, I was trying to simplify the problem so it could be better understood and forgot to rename that variable. I've just fixed it.

Comment: No problem, we appreciate the effort.

Comment: In the first example you get a array of objects; this doesn't make sense to me. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Daniel I have a function that given a value returns a vector. Now I have a 100x100 grid, when I feed this grid to the function it returns a (3,100,100) array. I just want to operate with these vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at more than the shape!

```
In [82]: a = np.array([1,1,1]) # Shape is (3,) 
    ...: b = np.zeros((3,10,10)) # Shape is (3,10,10) 
    ...: c = np.array([b[0], b[1], 0]) # Shape (3,)                             
In [83]:                                                                        
In [83]: c                                                                      
Out[83]: 
array([array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]),
       array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]),
       0], dtype=object)
In [84]: c.shape                                                                
Out[84]: (3,)
```

Yes, `c` just has 3 elements, but each is array or a scalar (the last 0).

```
In [85]: c-a                                                                    
Out[85]: 
array([array([[-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.]]),
       array([[-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.]]),
       -1], dtype=object)
```

So you managed to subtract 1 from each of those elements!

`c_wrong` is a very different array - it's 3d with a numeric dtype.  Replacing that `0` with `d[3]` makes all the difference.

```
In [88]: c_wrong.shape                                                          
Out[88]: (3, 10, 10)
In [89]: c_wrong.dtype                                                          
Out[89]: dtype('float64')
```

To subtract a (3,) from a (3,N,N) you have to adjust the dimensions of `a` to (3,1,1).  Then it can do proper broadcasting.

```
In [91]: c_wrong -  a[:,None,None]                                              
Out[91]: 
array([[[-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
        [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
        ....
        [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.]]])
```

I think it's just an accident that your `c-a` works.  By defining `c` with a `0` element, you created an `object` dtype array.  Math with object dtype arrays is nit-or-miss.  This subtraction happens to be one of those hits.  But don't count on it; there are lots ways in which math with such an array does not work - and it is always slower.

---

`c_wrong` is essentially the same thing as `b`.

---

The core of numpy is multidimensional numeric arrays.  `np.array` as a default tries to construct as high a dimensional numeric as it can.  In your `c_wrong` case it can make a 3d; in `c` is can't because of the scalar 0.  So it falls back on making a 1d object array.

The surest way to make an object array of the desired shape is to initial a 'blank' one, and fill it.  But even then filling can be tricky.  Here I managed to do it with:

```
In [92]: c3 = np.empty(3, object)                                               
In [93]: c3                                                                     
Out[93]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)
In [94]: c3[:] = list(b)                                                        
In [95]: c3                                                                     
Out[95]: 
array([array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       ....
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])], dtype=object)
In [96]: c3-a                                                                   
Out[96]: 
array([array([[-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
....
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.]])], dtype=object)
```

A fill that doesn't work:

```
In [97]: c3[:] = b                                                              
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
...
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,10,10) into shape (3)
```

`a[:,None,None]` doesn't look so ugly when you become familiar with broadcasting.

Compare the timings:

```
In [98]: timeit c_wrong-a[:,None,None]                                          
5.22 µs ± 6.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [99]: timeit c3-a                                                            
9.53 µs ± 20.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [100]: timeit c-a                                                            
7.66 µs ± 10.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Or with `dot`

```
In [103]: timeit np.dot(a, b.reshape(3,-1)).shape                              
2.44 µs ± 9.63 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [104]: timeit np.dot(a,c).shape                                              
10.9 µs ± 16.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [105]: timeit np.dot(a,c3).shape                                             
11.6 µs ± 30.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`dot` has very specific rules - the last axis of `a` must match the 2nd to the last of `b`.  That's why I used `reshape`.  And it passes the task to a fast 'blas' routine.

With the (3,) object array it does 1d `dot` product - but iteratively.

`@`, `matmul` works with the reshaped `b`, but not with `c` or `c3`. Same for `einsum`: `np.einsum('i,ijk->jk',a,b).shape` works, but not anything using `c`.

Comment: Oh! Great. I guess a[:,None,None] fixes it. Still a little bit ugly. Can't I have c with 3 elements, all of them arrays? Why can I have it with 3 elements (2 arrays + 1 scalar) but not 3 arrays?

Comment: It is not only that subtraction. All operators work great with the [array, array, scalar] version. Cross products, dot products, norm, etc. But as soon as I add the 3rd array it complaints about the broadcast

Comment: I would love to have a way to fix it modifying c_wrong (some how making it a 3 element array composed by 3 arrays). This way I wouldn't have to refactor any code

Comment: If I could somehow recast into this (N,) from a (N,M,M) everything would work fine. The following example is not as trivial as the subtraction:

a.dot(b)

*** ValueError: shapes (2,2) and (2,200,157) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 200 (dim 1)

Is not as trivial, it works when the shape is (2,) instead of (2,200,157)